# Try/Catch statement not catching exceptions

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, try-catch, numberformatexception

I'm trying to use a try/catch statement inside an inner class of an actionlistener but it does not catch the exceptions even when I deliberately trigger them. Here is the code excerpt:

```
btnPerformCalculation.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        double runtime = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(txtRunTime.getText()));
        double downtime = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(txtDownTime.getText()));
        double blockedtime = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(txtBlockedTime.getText()));
        double lineefficiency = 100 * runtime / (runtime + downtime + blockedtime);

        try {
            txtEfficiencyAnswer.setText(String.format("%.2f", lineefficiency));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Error:" + e.getMessage());
            txtRunTime.setText("0");
            txtDownTime.setText("0");
            txtBlockedTime.setText("0");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: would you please firstly tag you question which language you are using?

Comment: can you post the stack trace of the exception

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown from the try and not from the all the conversion done in the lines before it?

Comment: Are you sure the exception that is thrown is not a RuntimeException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only exceptions that you are catching are in `txtEfficiencyAnswer.setText(String.format("%.2f", lineefficiency));`. All other calculations (e.g. transforming possibly null text values into doubles are done before the try-block, and therefore not caught.

Assuming that `txtEfficiencyAnswer` is either a `JTextComponent` or a `JLabel`, the only obvious reason for an exception in that block would be a  `NullPointerException` if `txtEfficiencyAnswer` is `null`. If it is not null, then you will never enter the catch-block.

Comment: Thank you for the input. To respond, the txtEfficiencyAnswer is a JTextField. The IDE says that it is a NumberFormatException because I test the program by placing a letter when the program is expecting a number. When I enter numbers for the program it works fine. I try to do a try catch with a NumberFormatException but it still does not handle the exception.

Comment: @ForgottenKahz as I said: "All other calculations (e.g. transforming possibly null text values into doubles are done before the try-block, and therefore not caught". This also applies to text that cannot be parsed by Double.parseDouble thus throwing a NumberFormatException.

Comment: I revisited the code with the understanding that the number format error was originating before my try/catch resulting in the program crashing. I moved the try statement to encompass the string to double parsing resulting in the try/catch statement working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First, how are you sure that JOptionPane.showMessageDialog isn't throwing an exception?  I recommend putting output or logging as the first statement in your catch.  Second, not all "exceptions" are subclasses of Exception.  Try using    catch (Throwable e)   to see if the specific problem you are having gets solved.

I do not recommend leaving the catch(Throwable e) in your code since that will catch very low level jvm problems as well.  But it will at least help you understand what's happening.

Comment: The (Throwable e) did not work but it was worth the try. I get a NumberFormatException description in the IDE after the program crashes. I commented out the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog and put a simple System.out.Println() instead. Same issue. Program crashed and the dialog in the IDE mentioned the NumberFormatException. The origin of the this problem happens when I purposely type something other than a number into any of the fields therby triggering the bug that I want to catch.

Comment: As @bluesman suggested, that makes it clear the exception is raised by the code before the `try` block.

Comment: The number format error was originating before the try portion of the try/catch block. As soon as I moved the try{} the program caught the number format exceptions that came from the string to double parses.

Answer (score -4):

Probably `setText` throw `RuntimeException`.

1. Change catch statement to `catch (RuntimeException e)`
2. Print stacktrace.

Comment: `RuntimeException` extends `Exception`.